# The data I want to print appears as Instance of in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Text("Cari Adı : $task.cariadi! ",),
```

'task' It helps me to get the data inside the model I created named Task. I want to suppress the "cariadi" data. But when I write this code, the screen says "instance of 'Task'.cariadi! ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you neet to put {} :

```
Text("Cari Adı : ${task.cariadi!} ",),
```

Answer (score 0):

**dart:developer** library includes inspect functionality that allows debuggers to open an inspector on the object.

In order to use it you have to add:

```
import 'dart:developer';
```

And then you can see your variable/object in console with this code:

```
inspect(myVar);
```